# Не получается спарсить цену токена python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

```
@bot.message_handler(commands="token")
def token(message):

    r = requests.get("https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x2a69c59b8b493141d9f41b8f4fa724b60cd204e0")
    html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
    token_price = html.select('.mb-1 d-flex flex-column lh-1 > .text-success')


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{0}".format(token_price), parse_mode='html')
```

---

**UPD. Попробовал решение на selenium**:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands="token")
def token(message):
    URL = 'https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x2a69c59b8b493141d9f41b8f4fa724b60cd204e0'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.get(URL)
        print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

        token_price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.mb-1.d-flex.flex-column.lh-1 > .text-success')

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "{0}".format(token_price.text),
     parse_mode='html')

    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

**Ошибка**

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64619/devtools/browser/2d7a630e-2902-4501-8
e94-2dcce1b1ecb9
[1123/171216.156:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(780)] EGL Driver message (Critical) egl
Initialize: No available renderers.
[1123/171216.157:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1374)] eglInitialize D3D11 failed with
error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
```

**Другая ошибка после обновления драйвера хрома:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pars.py", line 9, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
        super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "
    goog",
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
        RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
        self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\nigga22nd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packa
    ges\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not crea
    ted: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
    Current browser version is 92.0.4515.159 with binary path C:\Program Files\Googl
    e\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    Stacktrace:
    Backtrace:
            Ordinal0 [0x01216903+2517251]
            Ordinal0 [0x011AF8E1+2095329]
            Ordinal0 [0x010B2848+1058888]
            Ordinal0 [0x010D0B9D+1182621]
            Ordinal0 [0x010CCA60+1165920]
            Ordinal0 [0x010CA2CF+1155791]
            Ordinal0 [0x010FAAAF+1354415]
            Ordinal0 [0x010FA71A+1353498]
            Ordinal0 [0x010F639B+1336219]
            Ordinal0 [0x010D27A7+1189799]
            Ordinal0 [0x010D3609+1193481]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x013A5904+1577972]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x01450B97+2279047]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x012A6D09+534521]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x012A5DB9+530601]
            Ordinal0 [0x011B4FF9+2117625]
            Ordinal0 [0x011B98A8+2136232]
            Ordinal0 [0x011B99E2+2136546]
            Ordinal0 [0x011C3541+2176321]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BC339A+18]
            RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x779C9ED2+99]
            RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x779C9EA5+54]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну я не понимаю почему у меня не парсится эта цена она находится в <span> я отношусь к нему но он мне возвращает None я не знаю объясните кто может

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Приведите исходный в вопросе как минимальный пример, чтобы его можно было запустить и увидеть вашу ошибку

Comment: @artem22nd, не используйте js-сниппеты для не js кода

Comment: @artem22nd, еще раз, не используйте js-сниппеты для не js кода. Выделяйте код через кнопку редактора `{}` или вручную, добавляя \`\`\` до и после кода. И вы последней правкой с ошибкой затерли код

Comment: Я подправил вопрос, в следующий раз, будьте внимательнее :) И не затирайте предыдущий код, я про тот, что с requests и bs4, ведь когда вы его удалили мой ответ потерял контекст

Comment: спасибо я первый раз просто здесь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут такие проблемы:

1. Сайт использует `javascript`. При загрузке страницы там контента не будет, т.к. он подгружается при выполнении `javascript`. В этом можно убедиться, выведя то, что приходит с сайта:

   ```
   print(r.text)
   ```

   Там не будет того тега, что вы пытаетесь получить
2. `bs4` и `html.parser` не умеют выполнять `javascript`
3. css-селектор неправильный. Если у элемента несколько значений в `class`, то они должны быть идти друг за другом без пробелов и каждому нужно добавить `.` (точку), вот так:

   ```css
   .mb-1.d-flex.flex-column.lh-1 > .text-success
   ```

Для первых двух проблем можно сделать через selenium:

- Установить так `pip install selenium`
- Нужно будет [скачать ему драйвер](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers)

  - В папку к скрипту или в переменные пути (путь до папки с драйвером)
  - Я использую Firefox, ему нужен `geckodriver`
  - Если нужно будет скрыть браузер, то [через опции задавайте ему флаг на headless](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/250935974ed34e10c7892e99e0e1d79ebf96c03c/html_parsing/2mz_me.py#L13)

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4bba3bee3efd6b8e0842acd6080c8bc579e9d127/html_parsing/poocoin_app.py)

```
import traceback

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


URL = 'https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x2a69c59b8b493141d9f41b8f4fa724b60cd204e0'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(URL)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    token_price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.mb-1.d-flex.flex-column.lh-1 > .text-success')
    print(token_price.text)

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Результат:

```
Title: 'PooCoin BSC Charts'
$0.00165060
```

Comment: Здравствуйте спасибо за ответ, проделал все по вашим указанием:
скачал chromedriver.exe правда 32бит был только на том сайте, и поместил к скрипту в папку вышел у меня такой код здесь не помещается я изменил в своем вопросе как только я запускаю команду /token на секунду появляется какое то окно и сразу же пропадает и в командной строке выдает это тоже оставлю в своем вопросе здесь не помещяется

Comment: @artem22nd, а если не в боте вызывать парсер, а отдельным скриптом, то такая же проблема?

Comment: Да только что попробовал

Comment: Возможно что тоне так с драйвером

Comment: @artem22nd, и судя по тому что я нашел в гугле, эта ошибка к Google Chrome относится. И то ли гугл хром нужно обновить (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48453823/5909792), то ли драйвер должен иметь определенную поддерживаемую версию (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53389256/5909792)

Comment: Я еще дополнил код ошибки

Comment: Сейчас обновил драйвер хрома и теперь другая ошибка может легче это сделать через firefix

Comment: @artem22nd, в ошибке написано: `This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96`. вообще, имеет смысл для таких скриптов держать отдельный драйвер и отдельный браузер (портабельный) и в `webdriver.Firefox()` ( `webdriver.Chrome()`) передавать пути к драйверу и exe браузера, чтобы была совместимость и не было расхождений :)

Comment: @artem22nd, но у меня с firefox не было таких приколов с версиями - старый драйвер работал с новым firefox и наоборот... Хотя, когда firefox'у нужно было обновляться, скрипты с selenium могли странно себя вести, что проходило после обновления браузера, но это нестрашно в моем случае, но лучше для таких вещей держать отдельный браузер как писал выше

Comment: Вообщем я сейчас скачал под firefox и все работает можно вас спросить еще а как мне этого бота передать заказчику и что бы у него тоже все работало?

Comment: @artem22nd, попробуйте скачать портальный firefox (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_Portable), в аргументы webdriver.Firefox передать относительные пути к exe браузера и к geckodriver, поместить их в папку проекта. Бота можно или собрать как exe (браузер и geckodriver рядом положить), но можно и скриптом + питон в папке, запускать их можно батником. А так, если будут вопросы по поводу сборки, то создайте новый вопрос

Comment: @artem22nd, проголосуйте мой ответ и примите его, пожалуйста :)

Comment: мне пока нельзя дольше надо сидеть здесь

Comment: @artem22nd, понимаю :) успехов вам :)