# Проблема с парсингом сайта на Python

Tags: python, парсер

Когда я пытаюсь вытащить html код карточки у меня ничего не выходит. Постоянно на выходе None.

Сайт на котором осуществляется парсинг: https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction

Код:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction'
headers = {
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}
page = r.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')

card1 = soup.find('div', class_='sc-eecfaa46-0 cioUee')
print(card1)
```

Текущий код после вмешательства Selenium:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import traceback

url = 'https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(url)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    card1 = driver.find_element(CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.sc-eecfaa46-1.dGKbaC.cejqaY')
    card2 = driver.find_element(CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.hWXObm')
    card3 = driver.find_element(CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.hWXObm')
    card4 = driver.find_element(CLASS_NAME, 'sc-eecfaa46-0.cioUee')
    card5 = driver.find_element(CLASS_NAME, 'sc-281cc2e7-0.cPpctU')

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Есть совет: попробуйте отредактировать вопрос, вставить код при помощи  тега "код" как текст. а то в Вас помидоры полетят. собственно, мой комментарий - это как раз такой пассивно-агрессивный помидор...

Comment: Проверьте, что тот тег есть: `print(page.text)`, возможно, сайт подгружает его через js (можно на сайте через инспектора отключить js и посмотреть что будет на странице)

Comment: @gil9red Да, я проверил этого тега там нет. Но каким образом тогда мне парсить?

Comment: Есть несколько способов: 1) если данные уже на сайте, но в json, тогда вытащить их 2) данные приходят извне, посмотреть какой запрос отправляет сайт для подгрузки и повторить его 3) использовать движок с javascript, типа selenium (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1353114/201445)

Comment: У меня появилась вот эта ошибка

Comment: @gil9red Title: 'Prediction | PancakeSwap - ...' Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\py projects\парсер на заказ\parser.py", line 14, in <module> card1 = driver.find_element(CSS_SELECTOR, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.sc-eecfaa46-1.dGKbaC.cejqaY') NameError: name 'CLASS_NAME' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указывать через by=By.CLASS_NAME

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import traceback

url = 'https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(url)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    card1 = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.sc-eecfaa46-1.dGKbaC.cejqaY')
    card2 = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.hWXObm')
    card3 = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-c4ec0fdf-0.hWXObm')
    card4 = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-eecfaa46-0.cioUee')
    card5 = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-281cc2e7-0.cPpctU')

except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```